# New LaTeX compiled book on Linux System Administration

Tags: linux, books, bash, linuxfedora

I just uploaded the first draft of a new book that I wrote on Linux System Administration. The source .tex documents and resources are available on my GitHub project site: [LSA](https://github.com/murraydavis/Linux-System-Administration). This is a project site, so I hope people would help contribute in making improvements. You will hopefully learn about the bash command line as well as how to compile a Latex document and resolve issues related to typesetting bash code. The book is being offered as an Open Source Project and thus anyone can clone my repository.

Comment: This does not contain a question about tex so is off topic, sorry.

Comment: "You will hopefully learn about ... how to compile a Latex document ", this is probably not the right place for that. :)